# Generate json schema in addition to, or from pact contract

Tags: pact

In my client code, I use json schemas to validate json responses (using [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)). I am planning to use [pact-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pact) to generate pacts to run against the provider for contract testing.

I would like a single source of truth for the schema that my client code uses during runtime validation and that the contract tests use during pact verification. Is there a way to generate json (or swagger) schemas from the pact file, or alternatively is there a library which uses the pact file itself for runtime validation of individual http responses (as opposed to just being used for contract verifications in contract tests)?

I realize this is a bit of a chicken and egg problem because I would need to first run the client code as part of a test run to generate the pacts (and in turn the json schema), so I would have to figure out a good work flow for that.

I also realize that contract tests should reduce the need for runtime validation, but contract testing is still not comprehensive enough to catch all real world scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no, although I believe there are a few OSS libraries that attempt to address this (none are official but I recall this coming up on forums at one point).

Either way, although the intentions are good we believe the task is [futile](https://docs.pact.io/faq/#why-doesnt-pact-use-json-schema). The two technologies are complimentary yet will no doubt evolve over time, making this more difficult to manage.

You could look to integrate with Swagger in a few ways, for example, the awesome folks at Atlassian have created a few you could look at [1][2].

[1] https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator

[2] https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-mock-validator

[3] https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/issues/28

Comment: Thanks for the references Matthew. These libraries look useful if I already have a swagger spec; however, I'm looking for something that will generate a swagger spec (or json schema) from a pact file. I would then use that swagger spec (or json schema) in my production code for runtime validations.